# C# Range to specific rating

Tags: c#, range

What is the best way to associate a range of numbers with a value, so that if the user inputs a number I can look up the value based on the range the number belongs to?

For example, I have the following `Rating` enum:

```
enum Rating
{
    A, B, C, D, E
}
```

And I want to assign a range of integers to each value, such that the numbers `1, 2, 3` are associated with `Rating.A`, numbers `4, 5, 6` are associated with `Rating.B`, numbers `7, 8, 9` are associated with `Rating.C`, etc...

Then, given some user input, I will return the appropriate enum value. For example, if the user enters `6` I will return `Rating.B`, or if they enter `10` I will return `Rating.D`.

I will have a lot of ranges (up to 100), so I do not want to write a bunch of `if / else if` statements to test all possible inputs. And it should be easy to add a new range / value into the collection.

Comment: I find it pretty unclear to understand what you're asking! :-( This sounds to me like "I have a problem, please provide the code to solve the problem". Try editing your answer by including what you've tried; if you've tried anything.

Comment: If you are indeed using an `enum` (called `Rating` for example), then given the user input `input`, and a range count of `3` (as in your example, groups of 3 represent each rating), then something like this should work: `return (Rating)((input - 1) / 3);`

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. I have written a solution and now it can't be posted.

Comment: Agreed. I edited it to try to make it more clear and voted to re-open it.

Comment: Please post solutions voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary<int, string>` where the `key` is the number and the `value` is the rating letter. Alternatively, the `value` could be an `enum`.

```
Dictionary<int, string> ratings = new Dictionary<int, string>();
ratings.Add(1, "A");
ratings.Add(2, "A");
ratings.Add(3, "B"); // etc..

// Get a rating by number:
var test = ratings[1]; // returns "A"
```

Adding your entries to the dictionary could also easily be done in a loop, if the pairs of values exist elsewhere.

A`Dictionary` has the benefit that it will not allow duplicate keys to be added and getting a rating is, basically, an O(1) operation. If there is the possibility that the number supplied may not be a valid key, `Dictionary` also includes methods to check that the key exists such as `ContainsKey(TKey)` and `TryGetValue(TKey, TValue)`.